# How to stop a given process with the linux task spooler

Tags: linux

I am not sure, whether this question relates to Linux in particular:

I use the tsp command to run small batchs of processes

```
tsp ./myScript.sh
```

which is then running

```
ID   State      Output               E-Level  Times(r/u/s)   Command [run=1/5]
1    running    /tmp/ts-out.woHIKK                           ./myScript.sh
```

but how can I kill this process? The only -K killing option with tsp seems to wipe the whole tsp server, it could be done using

```
ps -aux | grep myScript.sh | kill {}
```

But isn't there any tsp way to do it? It sounds to me like an obvious option.

Comment: `tsp -r <id>` ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: thanks, I was not sure to which extend this question fits within SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use kill:

```
kill $(tsp -p 1)
```

where 1 is the job ID.